# The output is not right when the number of rows and columns do not match

Tags: c++

The col-sum and tranpose functions work perfectly fine when i the numbers of rows and columns match but then it does not work when one differs from another

```
        #include<iostream>
        using namespace std;

        // protype
        void showcases();
        void accept(int Array[][40], int& a, int& b);
        void outputs(int Array[][40], int& a, int& b);
        int sum(int Array[][40], int& a, int& b);
        void row_sum(int Array[][40], int& a, int& b);
        void col_sum(int Array[][40], int& a, int& b); /// something wrong with this function. test it.
        void transposed(int Array[][40], int& a, int& b); /// something wrong with this function. test it.


        int main()
        {
            // variable declaration
            int a = 0, b = 0, choice = 0, A[20][40], n = 0, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

            // For loop execution
            for (int k = 0; choice != 7; k++)
            {
                //To showcase the given options 
                showcases();

                //input the user choice
                cin >> choice;

                cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl;

                /// if else ? you don't like them? + the unreasonable empty lines between the ifs
                //To perform a certain operation when a number is selected
                if (choice == 1)
                {
                    accept(A, a, b);
                    cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl << endl; /// remove this
                }
                else if (choice == 2)
                {
                    outputs(A, a, b);
                    cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl << endl; /// remove this
                }
                else if (choice == 3)
                {
                    cout << "Matrix elements sum = " << sum(A, a, b) << endl;
                    cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl << endl; /// remove this
                }
                else if (choice == 4)
                {
                    cout << "The sum of matrix rows are as following: -" << endl;
                    row_sum(A, a, b);
                    cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl << endl; /// remove this
                }
                else if (choice == 5)
                {
                    cout << "The sum of matrix rows are as following: -" << endl;
                    col_sum(A, a, b);
                    cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl << endl; /// remove this
                }
                else if (choice == 6)
                {
                    cout << "The transpose of the Matrix: " << endl;
                    transposed(A, a, b);
                    cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl << endl; /// remove this
                }
                else if (choice == 7)
                {
                    cout << "The application will exit now!!" << endl;
                    cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl << endl; /// remove this
                    return -1; /// remvoe this
                }
                else if (choice >= 8 || choice <= 0)
                {
                    cout << "Your choice is invalid" << endl;
                    cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl << endl;
                }
                /// add something here. figure it out

                /// add something here. figure it out
            }

            /// add something here. figure it out
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }

        // To input the elements 
        void accept(int Array[][40], int& a, int& b)
        {
            cout << "Enter  number of rows for matrix: ";
            cin >> a;
            cout << "Enter number of columns for matrix: ";
            cin >> b;

            cout << endl;

            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
                {
                    cout << "Enter elements of matrix " << "[" << i + 1 << "]" << " [" << j + 1 << "]: ";
                    cin >> Array[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        // TO output the elements 
        void outputs(int Array[][40], int& a, int& b)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
            {
                cout << "[";
                for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
                {
                    cout << Array[i][j];

                    if (j != b - 1)
                        cout << " ";

                    else if (j == b - 1)
                        cout << "]";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
        }

        // To find the total sum 
        int sum(int Array[][40], int& a, int& b)
        {
            int s = 0, i, j;
            for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < b; j++)
                {
                    s += Array[i][j];
                }
            }
            return s;
        }

        // To find the row sum
        void row_sum(int Array[][40], int& a, int& b)
        {
            int row_s = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
                {
                    row_s += Array[i][j];
                }
                cout << "R" << i + 1 << " Sum" << " = " << row_s;
                row_s = 0;
                cout << endl;
            }
            return;
        }

        // To find the column sum 
        void col_sum(int Array[][40], int& a, int& b)
        {
            int col_s = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
                {
                    col_s += Array[j][i];
                }
                cout << "C" << i + 1 << " Sum" << " = " << col_s;
                col_s = 0;
                cout << endl;
            }
            return;
        }

        // To transpose (To change the elements of rows and columns) the matrix 
        void transposed(int Array[][40], int& a, int& b)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
            {
                cout << "[";
                for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
                {
                    cout << Array[j][i];

                    if (j != b - 1)
                        cout << " ";

                    else if (j == b - 1)
                        cout << "]";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
            return;
        }

        // To display (To showcase) the available choiced 
        void showcases()
        {
            cout << "Menu" << endl;
            cout << "1. input elements" << endl;
            cout << "2. Display matrix" << endl;
            cout << "3. Sum of matrix elements" << endl;
            cout << "4. Sum of matrix rows" << endl;
            cout << "5. Sum of matrix columns" << endl;
            cout << "6. The transpose of elements" << endl;
            cout << "7. Exit" << endl;
            cout << "Choose among the options above: ";
        }


    when both the number of rows and columns are 3 this is my output when i select 2 to display the elements


[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]
[6 7 8]

and after transpose this is the new matrix
[1 4 6]
[2 5 7]
[3 6 8]

and col sum works fine
C1 Sum = 11
C2 Sum = 14
C3 Sum = 17

but if number of rows and columns differ this is the output 
Eg:  no of rows:4
 no of columns: 3

output after asking to display the output
[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]
[7 8 9]
[0 2 4]

output after the transpose
[1 4 7]
[2 5 8]
[3 6 9]
[-858993460 -858993460 -858993460]

sum of columns
C1 Sum = 12
C2 Sum = 15
C3 Sum = 18
C4 Sum = 1717986916
```

Any help is appreciated sorry if the format is wrong it was not letting me upload and it keep telling me either my code is not formmated or your post is mostly code

Comment: I recommend reading about `switch` and `case` statements.  The `switch` and `case` are good for processing menu selections (more readable IMHO).

Comment: What are the results after you used a debugger?  Which statements are causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Now i do not get the error anymore

{

```
// Variable Declaration
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, choice = 0, A[10][20], B[10][20], n = 0, x = 0;

    for (int k = 0; choice != 7; k++)
    {
        // Function Call
        showcases();

        // Input Choice Number
        cin >> choice;

        cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl;

        // Output Choice & Function Call
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            input_element(A, num1, num2);
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            display_matrix(A, num1, num2);
        }
        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            sum(A, num1, num2);
        }
        else if (choice == 4)
        {
            row_sum(A, num1, num2);
        }
        else if (choice == 5)
        {
            col_sum(A, num1, num2);
        }
        else if (choice == 6)
        {
            cout << "The transpose of the matrix is: " << endl;
            transp(A, num1, num2);
            cout << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 7)
        {
            cout << "The application will exit now!!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Your choice is invalid" << endl;
        }

        cout << "----------------------------------------------" << endl << endl;
    }

    // Exit
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

// Input Function
void input_element(int A[][20], int& m, int& n)
{
    cout << "Enter  number of rows for matrix: ";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "Enter number of columns for matrix: ";
    cin >> n;

    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << "Enter elements of matrix " << "[" << i + 1 << "]" << " [" << j + 1 << "]: ";
            cin >> A[i][j];
        }
    }
}

// Dispaly Matrix Function
void display_matrix(int A[][20], int& m, int& n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cout << "[";
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << A[i][j];

            if (j != n - 1)
                cout << " ";
            else if (j == n - 1)
                cout << "]";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

// Sum Function
void sum(int A[][20], int& m, int& n)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < m; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < n; column++)
        {
            sum += A[row][column];
        }
    }

    cout << "Matrix Elements Sum = " << sum << endl;
}

// Row Sum Function
void row_sum(int A[][20], int& m, int& n)
{
    cout << "The sum of the matrix rows are the following: -\n";

    int row_sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        row_sum = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            row_sum += A[i][j];
        }

        cout << "R" << i + 1 << " Sum = " << row_sum << endl;
    }

    return;
}

// Column Sum Function
void col_sum(int A[][20], int& m, int& n)
{
    cout << "The sum of the matrix columns are the following : -\n";

    int col_sum = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        col_sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            col_sum += A[i][j];
        }

        cout << "C" << j + 1 << " Sum = " << col_sum << endl;
    }

    return;
}

// Transpose Function
void transp(int A[][20], int& m, int& n)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        cout << "[";

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            cout << A[i][j];

            if (i != (m - 1))
            {
                cout << " ";
            }
            else if (i == (m - 1))
            {
                cout << "]";
            }
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}

// Showcase Menu Function
void showcases()
{
    cout << "Menu" << endl;
    cout << "1. Input Elements" << endl;
    cout << "2. Display Matrix" << endl;
    cout << "3. Sum Of Matrix Elements" << endl;
    cout << "4. Sum Of Matrix Rows" << endl;
    cout << "5. Sum Of Matrix Columns" << endl;
    cout << "6. Transpose Of Matrix" << endl;
    cout << "7. Exit" << endl;
    cout << "Choose among the options above: ";
}
```